# Do any OS X twitter apps integrate well with Notification Center?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, notifications, twitter

I'm looking for an app to let me keep the twitter integration from OS X (where I can tweet from Notification Center *(hereafter abbreviated NC)*) but also have my mentions from NC open in the app as opposed to opening Safari or another web browser.

I'm afraid the answer is no app can register/snatch the system twitter notifications [intercept Notification Center links in a stand alone app rather than Safari](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60942), but I'm going to ask in case this is possible.

Even if I have to turn off the OS X twitter notification in system preferences  or log out entirely to achieve this goal, do any OS X twitter clients integrate well with notification center for either DM or mention notifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tweetbot](http://tapbots.com/software/tweetbot/mac/) supports the Notification Center and adds clickable notifications that open in the app itself.

[image: Tweetbot Notifications preferences]

It does not intercept the standard Twitter notifications Mountain Lion added though, but as you mentioned, you can disable those to only see the Tweetbot ones. You can still tweet from the Notification Center after disabling standard Twitter notifications.

[image: Tweetbot in Notification Center]

Comment: This looks very promising. All the features I want and none of the confusion of opening a web page to respond to notifications.

Comment: U$10 bucks for notifications? no, thanks.